# Houndify : while using HoundifyVoiceSearchActivity to search audio, error : only regular white space(\r,\n,\t) is allowed between tokens

Tags: android, houndify

I use the Houndify android sdk sample project(v0.2.19) which downloaded from https://docs.houndify.com/sdks#android, but when I start HoundifyVoiceSearchActivity to search audio, I got the error as follow list:

> com.soundhound.android.houndify.sample E/HOUNDIFY_DEBUG: Error getting response
>                                                                                          com.hound.core.ParseException: Error reading object of type: PartialTranscript
>                                                                                              at com.hound.core.HoundMapper.read(HoundMapper.java:147)
>                                                                                              at com.hound.core.HoundMapper.read(HoundMapper.java:160)
>                                                                                              at com.hound.android.sdk.impl.connection.HttpVoiceConnection$ReceiveResponseThread.run(HttpVoiceConnection.java:321)
>                                                                                           Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
>                                                                                           at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4313edd0; line: 1, column: 2]
>                                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1586)
>                                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:521)
>                                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._throwInvalidSpace(ParserMinimalBase.java:472)
>                                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2283)
>                                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:601)
>                                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3828)
>                                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3773)
>                                                                                              at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2826)
>                                                                                              at com.hound.core.HoundMapper.read(HoundMapper.java:140)
>                                                                                               ... 2 more

I found the result json strings contain blank space(ASCII 32)，is it the reason of the erro? How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you download the latest Android SDK it is now resolved.  Basically, there was a configuration variable that will cause it not to work if you use unsupported languages.  You'll see it is now commented out in the latest version, which defaults it to English.

`builder.setInputLangIetfTag( Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() ); // Comment out this line`